# How to print the folder size

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a vba code that prints the folder names and # of items. I dont see any options to examine the folder size. How can i query the folder size for Outlook.MAPIFolder?

> 'Needs reference to MS Outlook Object Library

```
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objSourceFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim InboxMsg As Object
Dim Inbox As Outlook.Folder
Dim SystemEmails As String

 Dim filter As String
   Dim olParentFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olFolderA As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olFolderB As Outlook.MAPIFolder

Set objOutlook = Application
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI") '

Set olParentFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

For Each olFolderA In olParentFolder.Folders
    Debug.Print olFolderA.FolderPath, olFolderA.Items.Count, olFolderA.Folders.Count


    For Each olFolderB In olFolderA.Folders
        Debug.Print olFolderB.FolderPath, olFolderB.Items.Count
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/1201%20Outlook%20folder%20info.shtml

Answer (score 0):

The `MAPIFolder` or `Folder` class from the Outlook object model doesn't provide any size-related property. To get the job done you need to iterate over all items in a folder and count the folder size by summing every item size. For example:

```
For Each olFolderB In olFolderA.Folders
   Debug.Print olFolderB.FolderPath, olFolderB.Items.Count

   Dim count as Integer
   count = 0
   Dim folderItem as Object
   For Each folderItem In olFolderB.Items
      count = count + folderItem.Size
   Next

Next
```

Also, you need to use recursion to iterate over all nested folders in the store.

```
Private Sub processFolder(ByVal oParent As Outlook.MAPIFolder)

        Dim oFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
        Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem

        For Each oMail In oParent.Items

        'Get your data here ...

        Next

        If (oParent.Folders.Count > 0) Then
            For Each oFolder In oParent.Folders
                processFolder oFolder
            Next
        End If
End Sub
```